# plotting data with a series of start end dates

Tags: r

How would I go about plotting data with a series of start end date bands?

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
START<-as.POSIXct(c("2017-07-13 01:40:00 MDT", "2017-07-21 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-21 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-24 11:00:00 MDT",
        "2017-07-24 12:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-25 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-25 17:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-26 12:00:00 MDT",
        "2017-07-30 12:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-31 04:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-31 15:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-03 18:30:00 MDT",
        "2017-08-03 23:30:00 MDT", "2017-08-09 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-09 20:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-14 09:00:00 MDT",
        "2017-08-16 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 07:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 19:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-17 18:00:00 MDT",
        "2017-08-20 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-23 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-23 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-24 17:00:00 MDT",
        "2017-08-28 00:00:00 MDT"))

END<-as.POSIXct(c("2017-07-21 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-21 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-24 11:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-24 12:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-07-25 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-25 17:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-26 12:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-30 12:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-07-31 04:00:00 MDT", "2017-07-31 15:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-03 18:30:00 MDT", "2017-08-03 23:30:00 MDT",
    "2017-08-09 05:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-09 20:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-14 09:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 05:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-08-16 07:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-16 19:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-17 18:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-20 05:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-08-23 06:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-23 14:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-24 17:00:00 MDT", "2017-08-28 00:00:00 MDT",
    "2017-09-28 13:00:00 MDT"))

RATE<-c(1485, 0, 1485,  880, 1485, 0, 1485, 1100, 1485, 0, 1485, 1483, 1485, 0, 1485, 1419, 880, 0, 1419, 1485, 1419, 0, 1100, 419, 1100)

DF<-data.frame(START, END, RATE)
```

I would like to plot the 'Rate' on the y-axis and the dates on the x-axis. Is there a good method to go about doing this in ggplot or another plotting package?

Note: the end date is just when next rate starts. Also, I would like this as a line chart.

Comment: I would started by creating a dataframe whose date columns are actual dates, not factors.

Comment: Is the END date always just he START date lagged by one?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do it...

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF)+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=as.POSIXct(as.character(START)),
                  xmax=as.POSIXct(as.character(END)),
                  ymin=0,
                  ymax=RATE))
```

[image]

Alternatively, for a line plot, try

```
ggplot(DF)+
    geom_segment(aes(x=as.POSIXct(as.character(START)),
                     xend=as.POSIXct(as.character(END)),
                     y=RATE,
                     yend=RATE), size=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's great. But would be nice to view as a line chart. Is this possible?

Comment: Line plot option added above. You might experiment with `size=2` etc to make it clearer.